# Как изменить цвет вкладки QTabWidget с помощью stylesheet?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtabwidget

Вот имеющийся код приложения:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(500, 400)
        menu = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        menu.addTab(MyTab('Hello'), '1')
        menu.addTab(MyTab('wombat'), '2')
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(menu)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<center>{text}</center>')
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet('')  # here should be stylesheet
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Требуется получить вот это с помощью stylesheet или иным решением.

[image: желаемый результат]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, color):                                  # + color
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)                              
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<center>{text}</center>')
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(500, 400)
        menu = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        menu.addTab(MyTab('Hello', 'green'), '1')                      # 'green'
        menu.addTab(MyTab('wombat', 'yellow'), '2')                    # 'yellow'
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(menu)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, вы случаем не знаете, как сделать тоже с помощью palette изменение цвета вкладки QTabBar из QTabWidget?

Comment: @Paitor примите решение по данному вопросу. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаю

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1270172/409675