# Как получить доступ к вкладке QTabBar в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtabwidget

Мне нужно изменить цвет одной вкладки `QTabBar`, как это сделать? 
Как получить доступ к объекту именно этой вкладки, чтобы узнать какую то информацию о ней, или вот изменить цвет, текст и тд.

Еще меня интересует, могу ли я получить доступ к вкладке не только по индексу, но и по её состоянию. То есть могу ли я получить объект активной в данный момент вкладки, и что для этого нужно?

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(500, 400)
        menu = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        menu.addTab(MyTab('Hello'), '1')
        menu.addTab(MyTab('wombat'), '2')
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(menu)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<center>{text}</center>')
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Такой подойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен цветной зоопарк, то попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, colors, parent=None):
        super(TabBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mColors = colors

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            if opt.text in self.mColors:
                opt.palette.setColor(
                    QtGui.QPalette.Button, self.mColors[opt.text]
                )
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        d = {
            "All":        QtGui.QColor("yellow"),
            "purchase":   QtGui.QColor("#87ceeb"),
            "POS Sales":  QtGui.QColor("#90EE90"),
            "Cash Sales": QtGui.QColor("pink"),
            "invoice":    QtGui.QColor("#800080"),
        }
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(d))

        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "All")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "purchase")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "POS Sales")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "Cash Sales")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "invoice")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    # Внимание!  работает только в том случае, если вы используете стиль fusion, ... 
    app.setStyle("fusion")                                                     # !!!
    
    w = TabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Цвет можно поменять через [QSS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) ([пример стилей для QTabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar))

Добавьте в конструктор `MyWindow` строчку:

```
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QTabBar::tab:first {
                background: yellow;
                color: red;
            }        
        """)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для получения текущей вкладки используйте метод `currentIndex` у `QTabWidget` или у `QTabBar`. А взаимодействовать можно будет через методы `setTab*` и `tab*` у `QTabBar`, например [setTabText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#setTabText) и [tabText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#tabText). В вашем коде это было бы так:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
...

        menu.tabBar().setTabTextColor(1, Qt.red)
```

Comment: А если требуется поменять цвет другой вкладки

Comment: @Paitor, вместо `first` можно указать `last`, но есть ли возможность для конкретной вкладки указать стили не нашел

Comment: То есть было бы 5 вкладок, указать стили для 2 и 4 я бы не смог? И еще вопрос, есть ли решения не с StyleSheet, а использованием palette?

Comment: @Paitor, цвет конкретной вкладки можно будет через `setTabTextColor` поменять, фон не нашел. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#setTabTextColor

Comment: Спасибо, очень жаль

Comment: @Paitor, раз он позволяет задавать цвет вкладок, то наверняка можно на это повлиять, думаю не стоит вариант с palette оставлять. Или вот еще вариант, но тут уже через наследование QTabBar и переопределение события рисования виджета: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22606784/5909792

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые ответы на ваши вопросы:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<center style="color: red"><h1>{text}</h1></center>')
        self.label.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(500, 400)
        
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.menu.addTab(MyTab('Hello'), 'Tab 1')
        self.menu.addTab(MyTab('World'), QIcon('Ok.png'), 'Tab 2')
        self.menu.addTab(MyTab('wombat'), 'Tab 3')
        
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Click me')
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.menu)
        vbox.addWidget(button)

        self.menu.tabBarClicked.connect(self.handle_tabbar_clicked)

    def handle_tabbar_clicked(self, index):
        print(f'''
            {self.menu.tabText(index)}, 
            {index}, 
            {self.menu.currentWidget().label.text()}
        ''')
        
    def onClicked(self):
        index = self.menu.tabBar().currentIndex()
        print(f'текущий QTabBar -> {index} -> {self.menu.tabText(index)}')


qss = '''

QTabWidget::pane {
    border: 2px solid #1687a7;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    
    background-color: #d3e0ea;
}
/* QTabBar ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

QTabBar {
    background: magenta;
}
QTabBar::tab {
    background: rgb(34, 137, 163);
    color: white;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background-color: rgb(48, 199, 184,);
    color: #000000;
}
'''        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]